# Creating recurring appointments in MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, appointments

I am conducting a training for some of my colleagues and I am putting up an appointment in MS Outlook (so, that people do NOT book my time for anything else!).

It is for this week, starting this Tuesday, 23 November, 2010 and ends on Friday, 26 November, 2010.

I create a New Appointment.

I enter the subject as

> Training - Day #1

I enter the location as

> Meeting Room 1.44

I click on the recurrence button and fill in the details as required. Now, all is fine. However, the subject reads as Training Day #1 for all of the appointments.

Is there any way that I can have my subject read as Training Day #1, Training Day #2 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Outlook's idea of a recurring appointment shows the same title for each occurrence.

Comment: So, there is no way that we can have a different title? Hmm...that is not good at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you're naming the series, not the appointment.  "Training #1-12".  I believe you can edit the details of individual appointments after the series has been created, but each update will be sent to users separately.

### Steps

1. create recurring meeting with single name "Meeting-Series", they will all be created with the same name
2. edit each instance (12/1, 12/8, 12/15 ...) to rename each one to the correct number in the title

Comment: OK. Do we have an option of naming the "appointment" rather than the "series"?

Comment: You'd have to open each appointment individually and change the subject.  I've seen this done for weekly team meetings - the manager will add some context like specific topic to the 'subject' of the recurring meetings a day or two before that meeting (so team members can prepare their thoughts on the topic).  If only 12 then maybe it is reasonable to edit each item individually.  I editted the answer to make the steps clearer.